# I'm not specifying the form action but it (automatically) gives different values in some cases

Tags: forms, cakephp

I'm creating my form using the Form helper, so the action of the form is specified automatically....

this form is used for editing a post..
so, the URL has the structure: `mywebsite.com/posts/edit/id`
and the form's action should be automatically generated as `posts/edit/id`

but the problem is, in some cases, I open the HTML code and I find that the form's action is only `posts/edit` without the `id` which causes the update to fail...

I spent a lot of time to figure out what situation brings this wrong action:

- i'm generating fields dynamically (using javascript & ajax) depending on the post's category..
- when the value of one of the dynamically generated fields is invalid, the generated action becomes `posts/edit` !!

I really need help, cuz I don't know why this is happening !!!
and I don't wanna waste more time digging into the core of cakephp...
so, if any of cakephp experts has an idea about this, plz help me !!

thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use the url parameter, which allows you to explicitly define a url for the form:

```
echo $form->create('Post', array('url' => $html->url(array('action'=>'edit', $id))));
```

Comment: now i'm doing this already...but i want to understand what is happening !!

Comment: Take a look at the source code for [FormHelper](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/form-helper/#line-245) then ;) You can see that it first checks for a URL parameter. Alternatively it will use the action parameter or default to using the same action as the form.  When it uses the action parameter, you can't pass additional values to it (such as an id), like you would with $html->url().

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `$id` probably isn't getting set, because it should be getting passed along if it is. You need to make sure it's set to edit the record in question. Make sure your javascript is including the hidden field with the record's `id` in it.

Normally done like this, with the form helper: `echo $this->Form->input('id');`

Also, if one of the fields is invalid, the form shouldn't actually be submitting properly, if you are using cake's validation, so this is to be expected.